# Tracking a ball (using EmguCV)

Tags: opencv, visual-tracking

I've got a video of a ball, I've done background subtraction (using MOG2) to isolate the change in the image. And I'm performing a blur to remove some of the noise caused by light/shadows/etc.

So, now that I have clearer image to work on, I'm using `GoodFeaturesToTrack` to and `OpticalFlow.PyrLK` to draw lines from frame to frame, to track the motion.

However, I still don't know how I can differentiate which motion is caused by a ball, and which is random, a person, etc... I'm just drawing lines tracking points that moved...but how do I determine which, if any, of those points were actually on the ball?

This is the code I currently have

```
class Program
{
    static Timer _myTimer;
    static Capture _capture;
    static ImageViewer _viewer;
    static readonly BackgroundSubtractorMOG2 MogDetector = new BackgroundSubtractorMOG2(0, 32.0f, true);
    static int _frameNumber;

    private static Image<Gray, byte> _previousFrame;
    private static PointF[] _previousFeatures;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        const int fps = 30;

        _myTimer = new Timer();
        _myTimer.Interval = 1000 / fps;
        _myTimer.Tick += MyTimerTick;
        _myTimer.Start();

        _capture = new Capture(@"C:\source\dungeon\ComputerVision\Camera\App_Data\converted.avi");
        _viewer = new ImageViewer();
        _viewer.ShowDialog(); 
    }

    private static void MyTimerTick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var rawFrame = _capture.QueryFrame();
        var originalRoi = rawFrame.ROI;
        var roi = new Rectangle(0, rawFrame.Height / 2, rawFrame.Width, rawFrame.Height - rawFrame.Height / 2);

        var cropFrame = rawFrame
            .GetSubRect(roi)
            .Convert<Gray, byte>()
            .SmoothGaussian(17);

        if (_frameNumber++ < 100) 
            MogDetector.Update(cropFrame.Convert<Bgr, byte>());
        else
            MogDetector.Update(cropFrame.Convert<Bgr, byte>(), 1.0e-5);

        //Find the motion
        var motionMask = MogDetector.ForegroundMask
            .ThresholdBinary(new Gray(250), new Gray(255)) // Removes shadows
            //.Erode(3).Dilate(3) // Removes small artifacts that aren't really moving
            ;

        //var motion = frame.Copy(motionMask);
        //var motion = rawFrame.Add(motionMask);
        var motion = rawFrame.Copy();
        motion.ROI = roi;
        motion.Add(motionMask.Convert<Bgr, byte>());

        if (_previousFrame != null)
        {
            PointF[] returnFeatures;
            byte[] status;
            float[] trackError;

            _previousFeatures = _previousFrame.GoodFeaturesToTrack(100, .01, .1, 3)[0];
            OpticalFlow.PyrLK(_previousFrame, motionMask, _previousFeatures, new Size(15, 15), 5, new MCvTermCriteria(5), out returnFeatures, out status, out trackError);

            //Console.WriteLine("Features Found:" + returnFeatures.Length);
            for (var i = 0; i < returnFeatures.Length; i++)
            {
                var prevPoint = _previousFeatures[i];
                var currPoint = returnFeatures[i];
                var state = status[i];
                var error = trackError[i];

                var line = new LineSegment2D(new Point((int)prevPoint.X, (int)prevPoint.Y), new Point((int)currPoint.X, (int)currPoint.Y));
                var travelUp = prevPoint.Y - currPoint.Y;
                var travelLeft = prevPoint.X - currPoint.X;

                //if (state != 1 || !(line.Length > 15) || !(error < 10)) 
                if (!(state == 1 && line.Length > 15 && error < 10))
                    continue;

                motion.Draw(line, new Bgr(Color.Red), 3);
                Console.WriteLine("Error: {0}, Up: {1}, Left: {2}, Length: {3}", 
                    error, travelUp, travelLeft, line.Length);
            }
        }
        _previousFrame = motionMask;

        motion.ROI = originalRoi;
        _viewer.Image = motion;
    }
}
```

A few other things that I'm struggling on are what the different thresholds, and values mean that I'm passing into `GoodFeaturesToTrack`, `Mog2`, etc, the documentation tends to just say "it's the threshold" ...

Thanks.

Comment: I'm reading http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas%E2%80%93Kanade_method but the math...way way over my head.

Comment: I think http://www.stackoverflow.com  would be better place for the question

Comment: Why? It's not a question of code...It's a question about cv, I need help understanding how to find and track an object